# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MMWormhole"

Tags: ios, cordova, watchkit, cordova-plugins, apple-watch

I am getting following error while build

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MMWormhole",
referenced from:       objc-class-ref in InterfaceController.o ld: symbol(s)
not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit 
code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have installed plugin using
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-apple-watch

I did not got any libmmwormhole.a file with plugin installation

I had added reference of MMWormhole.h in InterfaceController.m.

Comment: try setting the build active architecture to NO

Comment: @Mr.T I tried with that, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

In your file InterfaceController, you use the class with a name containing "Wormhole."  It's not defined anywhere, so the linker can't put it together. It looks like a library is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find in project MMWormhole or Wormhole if it's in and there is in project files inside Compile Sources than go Project -> Clean Build Folder and delete User/Libraries/Developer/Xcode/Derived Data folder
If it's not -- you need add library with it in your project.